# Bootstrap 3 - navbar dropdown not working on extra html pages

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, less, navbar

I have made a website in dreamweaver using bootstrap 3 and less.

I have used navbar default and customised it.

I have just added some extra pages to my site, such as about.html and blog.html

however, on these extra pages the dropdown menu doesn't seem to work. It **does** work fine on the homepage, with exactly the same code.

I have wrapped with a < li > already and just copy and pasted all the html into my new html files as follows, to have the navbar there on each page. Please advise if I have done something wrong, I am pretty much a complete beginner.Thanks!

```
<div class="header clearfix">
    <nav class="text-center">
        <ul class="nav nav-pills">
            <li role="presentation" class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li>
                <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"   role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Our Services <span class="caret"></span></a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                    <li><a href="#">jhdhalbalb</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">hdjdjjdj</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">bdjdshbd</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li role="presentation"><a href="About us.html">About us</a></li>
            <li role="presentation"><a href="Blog.html">Blog</a></li>
            <li role="presentation"><a href="#">Contact</a></li> 
        </ul>
    </nav>
</div>
```

Comment: Have you checked your [console](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/debug/console/?hl=en) to see if both jQuery and BootstrapJS are loading on all your pages?

Comment: Should I be putting the links at the bottom as I have done in the index.html page? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this to the head section of all your pages:

```
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Optional theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-fLW2N01lMqjakBkx3l/M9EahuwpSfeNvV63J5ezn3uZzapT0u7EYsXMjQV+0En5r" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-0mSbJDEHialfmuBBQP6A4Qrprq5OVfW37PRR3j5ELqxss1yVqOtnepnHVP9aJ7xS" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Sometimes bootstrap local files don't work - doing this will let you know if you should re-download them. This is something that has happened to me before.

Also your HTML is very messy, making it hard to really look through. Try cleaning it up a bit and making sure you're following [W3 standards](https://www.w3.org/standards/webdesign/) so you can follow your code and others can read it.

You should also read this: http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#dropdowns Bootstrap dropdowns require an extra .js plugin.

Comment: Hey, thanks for this I will have a go. That makes sense. I haven't put any links in my other html files, I shall do that. I have dropdown.js, it is in my node folder. Works fine on homepage, just not the extra pages I have manually added

Comment: Did you mean my code is messy as in badly written or just badly laid out? If that latter it will be the way I copy and pasted in here. If it's badly written, how do I write it better? Please advise. Have been using W3 schools

Comment: I have it working now, I hadnt added bootstrap and jquery links in the html files for extra pages. thanks!

Comment: Just as a rule of thumb - don't use W3schools. They are not affiliated with the W3 Consortium. The Mozilla Developer Network is a better resource, most front-end guys only use W3schools for quick refreshers. By messy, I meant that you should try to make sure your tags are aligned with their closing tags and you should use whitespace to make the code more readable. [Here](https://css-tricks.com/examples/CleanCode/Beautiful-HTML.png) is an example of "good" html.